# JButton background color not changing with getSystemLookANdFeel in windows

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to change background color of JButton with system look and feel on windows using UIManager. 
Code snippet

```
UIManager.put("Button.contentAreaFilled",false);
UIManager.put("Button.background",Color.white);
UIManager.put("Button.foreground",Color.black);
UIManager.put("Button.opaque",true);
```

But its showing the underlying OS color. Can someone suggest a workaround?

Comment: when u want to change color. after click or before?.

Comment: before click itself when the frame is getting loaded

Comment: you better to use JavaFx

Comment: @RishabhKhandelwal please show how you set your Look and Feel. Better provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your own button to realize your own drawing logic.
Here's a sample implementation:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ColorButton extends JButton {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Color bg;

    public ColorButton(String text) {
        super(text);

        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setText(text);
        label.setOpaque(true);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackground(Color bg) {
        if(!UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName().endsWith("WindowsLookAndFeel")) {
            super.setBackground(bg);
        }

        this.bg = bg;
        if(label != null) {
            label.setBackground(bg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setForeground(Color fg) {
        super.setForeground(fg);
        if(label != null){
            label.setForeground(fg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Rectangle rectangle = getBounds();
        rectangle.x = 3;
        rectangle.y = 3;
        rectangle.width -= rectangle.x * 2;
        rectangle.height -= rectangle.y * 2;

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setColor(bg);
        g2d.fill(rectangle);
    }
}
```

And this is a test:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ColorButtonFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        ColorButton button = new ColorButton("Click Me...");
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Click Me...");
        button1.setOpaque(true);
        button1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        panel.add(button1);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why can't I simply set property as UIManager.put("Button.background",Color.white);

Comment: Well, in WindowsLookAndFeel has no effect. But even if it worked, you would change the color of all the buttons, and hardly that's what it is.

Comment: But some changes are working fine when I am using it with JTextArea or scrollpane

Comment: I have no idea why it does not work for the buttons. I tested it with windows 7 and java 8.

Comment: @RishabhKhandelwal: The button's UI delegate decides if it's opaque; you have change it or replace it.

Comment: @trashgod I didnt get you . Can you please elaborate